# Unable to get updated props/states

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, components, redux-thunk

In my action class I have a method as below

```
export const userSettingFetch = () => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/userSettings`)
      .on('value', snapshot => {

        dispatch({ type: USER_SETTING_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val()});
      });
  };
};
```

Once the above method being invoked, it will dispatch to `UserSettingReducer` reducer and being stored into `userSettingData` state which defined as below:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  userSetting_DailyLimit: '',
  userSetting_City: '',
  userSetting_DisplayName: '',
  userSettingData: null
};
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_SETTING_UPDATE:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value };
    case USER_SETTING_SUBMISSION_SUCCESS:
      return state;
    case USER_SETTING_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, userSettingData: action.payload };//action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And below is my `combineReducers` code:

```
export default combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer,
  userSetting: UserSettingReducer
});
```

Now come to my component as below;

```
class MainScreen extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('inside MainScreen componentWillMount method');
    this.props.userSettingFetch();
    //console.log('Name is: '+this.props.userSettingData.userSetting_DisplayName);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <Text>{this.props.userSettingData.userSetting_DisplayName}</Text>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth, userSetting }) => {
  const { email, password, error, loading } = auth;
  const { userSettingData } = userSetting;

  return { email, password, error, loading, userSettingData };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ userSettingFetch })(MainScreen);
```

And below is the console log when the app running:

[image]

Everything looks perfect to me however I got exception saying `userSettingData` is undefined?

Comment: What is the INITIAL_STATE for userSetting?

Comment: Would be helpful and faster if you could provide Plunker sample or something like that.

Comment: @MukeshSoni: INITIAL_STATE for userSetting is null

Comment: @MukeshSoni: Please refer to my question again where I've included the `INITIAL_STATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the INITIAL_STATE, userSettingData is null and you are trying to access `userSetting_DisplayName` property of `userSettingData`. You can put a check there -

```
{this.props.userSettingData 
  ? <Text>{this.props.userSettingData.userSetting_DisplayName}</Text> 
  : <Text>User setting data still not available</Text>
}
```

Or you can initiatize `userSettingData` to an empty object

Your payload is an object which has a random key and the object you want is a value for that key. To get the object from there you can use Object.entries -

```
payload: Object.entries(snapshot.val())[1]
```

Comment: I've tried to set the `INITIAL_STATE` for userSettingData to `{}`, error is no longer throwing but seems like no response. Then I try at my component change it to `<Text>{JSON.stringify(this.props.userSettingData)}</Text>` I can see the object in JSON format being printed out but not understand the reason

Comment: Your payload is an object which has a random key and the object you want is a value for that key. To get the object from there you can use Object.entries - 

    payload: Object.entries(snapshot.val())[0]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, in order to make this works I need to set `Object.entries(snapshot.val())[0]}` as payload in `userSettingFetch` method and in my reducer I need to set something like `userSettingData: action.payload[1]`

Comment: Indeed managed to get the data as expected thou it seems hardcoding with index `1`..not quite comfortable with that haha

Comment: index 1? That's weird. What does the complete result for snapshot.val() look like?

Comment: complete result for `snapshot.val()` is exactly the one shown as screenshot in my question. Using `Object.entries(snapshot.val())[0]}`, it takes the first object and this object apparently have first item as ID and second item is the actual object. That's why need the index 1

Comment: Ah yes, Object.entries converts the object into an array of two tuples (array with two values). Each internal array has the [key, value], where key is the property name and value is the property value. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `INITIAL_STATE` does not include `userSettingData` object before `userSettingFetch` API call. As a result, you got `userSettingData` is `undefined`. One of the options is to show spinner until the moment `userSettingData` is available in the state however it would require additional changes to your application.

Another case could be `mapStateToProps` when you are destructing an object `userSetting` that does not contain `userSettingData` key.

Comment: Please refer to my question again as I've included my `INITIAL_STATE`. I suspecting the same where `userSetting` does not contain `userSettingData` key and that's why I'm sharing my `mapStateToProps` function.